# How do I .loadUrl variable instead of url?

Tags: android

I load my ad banner page inside of app like

```
WebView reklam1goruntule = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.reklam1);

    WebSettings webSettings = reklam1goruntule.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    reklam1goruntule.loadUrl("http://mywebside.com/adbanner.html");
reklam1goruntule.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

I would like to use change this url any time using by firebase.And load to new url.So I'll use like..

```
myRef.child("Ads").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Banners").setValue("Ad240url");
```

But how do ı need replace this ?

```
reklam1goruntule.loadUrl("http://mywebside.com/adbanner.html");
```

it's need to looks like

```
reklam1goruntule.loadUrl("Ad240url");
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. `"Ad240url"` is not a valid url, so you cannot load that as a url string. Do you want that string to translate to `"http://mywebside.com/adbanner.html"`?

Comment: No "Ad240url" is firebase database variable and its content url address.